# jQuery checking if IP address are within the range

Tags: javascript, jquery, networking, ip, ip-address

I want to be able to check that two IP address are within the range. So if a user enter something like `10.10.10.0` and `10.10.10.10` then it will pass the validation and enter that address into the database. Then want to check if a users enter something like 10.9.10.10 that would be invalid and I would ask the user to correct the error. My thinking is that I would convert the IP address into `long` and then make sure the `endIpAddrToLong` is greater then the `startIpAddrToLong`

> Is this the correct Logic to do something like that? Can I just convert the IP's to longs and compare them? The message I would display to the user would be IP address ranges cannot be defined outside the Address field.

```
    $('#button-validate').on('click', function() {
       let startIpAddr = $("#txtstartIpAddr").val();
       var startIpAddrToLong = parseInt(IpAddressToLong(startIpAddr));
       
       let endIpAddr = $("#txtendIpAddr").val();
       var endIpAddrToLong = parseInt(IpAddressToLong(endIpAddr));
      
       if (endIpAddrToLong >  startIpAddrToLong) {
            console.log('success');
          $("#validate").val("True");
        }
       
    });
    
    function IpAddressToLong(ip){
            return ip.split('.').map((octet, index, array) => {
        return parseInt(octet) * Math.pow(256, (array.length - index - 1));
            }).reduce((prev, curr) => {
        return prev + curr;
        });
```

}

working sample
http://jsfiddle.net/tjmcdevitt/mdkx9h0w/31/

Something like this is what I am trying to do.
[image]

Comment: What seems to go wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the range", but if you mean that the IP addresses are in the same subnet, then you need to bring the subnet mask into this. 10.10.10.0 and 10.9.10.10 are in the same subnet if the subnet mask is 255.0.0.0.

Comment: I updated with a picture I hope it help explain what I am trying to do.